# How can I call two methods, first one returns void observable and second one returns observable?

Tags: rxjs

I am calling two method.
complete() returns void observable
getDetails() returns observable
I am calling second one in map.
I wonder if this is correct way or is there any other way?

I called complete() method which updates flag as completed and returns void observable. and I need to call getDetails method which returns observable.

```
this.dataService.complete(input)
.pipe(  
   map(() => {this.dataService.getDetails(id)
                  .subscribe((result) => {
                        console.log(result);
                   })
       })
).subscribe();
```

I get result as expected but I am beginner for rxjs. 
If this is wrong, please let me know correct way. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid nested subscribe() 
Try use `concatMap`, `mergeMap` , `switchMap` etc to continue the stream

```
this.dataService.complete(input)
.pipe(  
   switchMap(() => this.dataService.getDetails(id)),
   tap(result=>console.log(result))
).subscribe();
```